# Using values in a column as field names for new table

Tags: mysql

I need to build a temporary table where the field names are the values in a column of another table. This second table can (and will) change during development of the website, so I can't hardcode the field names into my routine.

As an example of what I mean, consider this as the source table, aptly named "sourcetable":

```
field_id    fieldname
1           profile_name
2           profile_surname
5           profile_address_street
```

Then I would need to make a table that looks like this:

```
profile_name    profile_surname profile_address_street
John            Doe             Baker Street
```

I tried this:

```
create temporary table if not exists newtable(
  select fieldname from sourcetable
);
```

But that returns a table that just contains the "fieldname" column from "sourcetable". Does anyone know a clean and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest and cleanest way would be to build the `CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE` (or even a plain `SELECT` query - depending on how you use the stuff) statement in the application code using the data in `sourcetable`, and the just running it.

You won't be able to do anything flexible in pure SQL there, or maybe by using stored procedures (but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Hi Romain,

Thanks for the quick reaction. I had already figured out something like that, indeed, but the (slightly messy) mixed-technology approach of the project requires all this to be done in a - as you mentioned - stored procedure as opposed to in the application logic.